# How to set secret variable for gitlab-runner on self hosted instance?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have gitlab-runner configured with my gitlab account. On hosted environment I am able to see secret `echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` but locally it is always blank.

`gitlab-runner exec docker build`

How to set the secret locally also?

Comment: Are you maybe using a different branch for your local environment? Protected  keys don't get passed to non-protected branches.